# When are the English football competitions' schedules published?

Tags: football, english-premier-league, schedule

This October, I will be visiting the Rugby World Cup and I would like to combine that with visiting other sports events. For sure, I want to visit one, but probably more, football matches. So, I wonder when the schedules get published.

I know it will not be any time soon, since the leagues and playoffs haven't even finished yet. However, I would like to have some indication. Notice that this question is about all English professional leagues, so from Premier League to Conference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Barclays Premier League FAQ](http://www.premierleague.com/content/premierleague/en-gb/contact-us.html)

> The Fixture List is usually announced in mid-June, approximately two months prior to the start of the new season.

As for the Football League (Championship, League 1, League 2) [their website](http://www.football-league.co.uk/global/keydates.aspx) has already announced the fixture release date as **Thursday 18th June** for the 2015/16 season.

Answer (score 1):

I found this link (http://www.totalsportek.com/football/premier-league-fixtures/) that says the fixtures will be released on the 17th June around 9am Uk time.